# Groups/Communities in Facebook snap dataset using networkx in python

Tags: python, python-2.x, facebook

I was using facebook dataset and making a graph on it. But was not been able to find different groups/communities in it. The code was using is this:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

g = nx.read_edgelist('facebook_combined.txt', create_using=nx.Graph(), nodetype=int)
print nx.info(g)

sp = nx.spring_layout(g)
nx.draw_networkx(g, pos=sp, with_labels=False, node_size=35)
# plt.axes('off')
plt.show()
```

The result i was getting is this:
[image]

But was not been able to find groups or communities in it.

The link to the dataset is [here](https://snap.stanford.edu/data/facebook_combined.txt.gz)

The source to the is [here](https://snap.stanford.edu/data/egonets-Facebook.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching and researching to find the solution to this question i came up with this answer:

**To find/detect communities in facebook snap dataset:**

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import community


'''Exploratory Data Analysis'''
g = nx.read_edgelist('facebook_combined.txt', create_using=nx.Graph(), nodetype=int)
print nx.info(g)

'''Simple Graph'''
# sp = nx.spring_layout(g)
# nx.draw_networkx(g, pos=sp, with_labels=False, node_size=35)
# # plt.axes("off")
# plt.show()

'''Graph with communities dectection'''
spring_pos = nx.spring_layout(g)
parts = community.best_partition(g)
values = [parts.get(node) for node in g.nodes()]

plt.axis("off")
nx.draw_networkx(g, pos=spring_pos, cmap=plt.get_cmap("jet"), node_color=values, node_size=35, with_labels=False)
plt.show()
```

this will give the following output:

[image]